# Bookshelf query joining mulitiple tables with where criteria

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

My generic question is if you have a datamodel something like A(1) -> B(many) -> C(many) -> D(many) and you want to get out objects of D, but you only have criteria on A, how can you do it?

Specifics here:

```js
const Contact = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  sites: function () {
    return this.hasMany(Site);
  },
});

const Contacts = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: Contact,
});

const Site = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  siteAttendances: function () {
    return this.hasMany(SiteAttendance);
  },
  siteSupervisor: function () {
    return this.belongsTo(Contact);
  },
});

const Sites = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: Site,
});

const SiteAttendance = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  site: function () {
    return this.belongsTo(Site);
  },
  incidents: function () {
    return this.hasMany(Incident);
  },
});

const SiteAttendances = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: SiteAttendance,
});

const Incident = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  siteAttendance: function () {
    return this.belongsTo(SiteAttendance);
  }
});

const Incidents = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: Incident,
});
```

I've got a Contact ID (A object), but I want objects that are Incidents (D object) and I'm wondering can I do this with only bookshelf.js?  To complicate things, for every Contact, there are MANY Sites and SiteAttendances, but only a few Incidents.  One Contact ID will yield many Sites, so there might be a way to do it from Incident to Site with a `through`, but I haven't been able to get that to work.  I don't think starting at Contact and doing `withRelated` all the way down is the right approach (since there are so many of Site and SiteAttendance), but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Badly you cannot use `through` for deep relations. And `withRelated` option, will make 3 queries to fetch back the contact's `incidents`.
If you don't care, `withRelated: "sites.siteAttendances.incidents"` will save you.

Comment: This is what I thought.  For things like this, is there a consensus around dropping out to knex vs sticking with bookshelf?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem and I also wondered if there is some "Bookshelf-y" way to do it. I have implemented some knex-based code and it works. That is, it outputs a single *SELECT* statement with the given joins.

It translates to your example approximately like so:

```
  const exampleVal = Incident.forge();
  const toSiteAt = exampleVal.siteAttendance();
  const incTable = toSiteAt.relatedData.parentTableName;
  const saTable  = toSiteAt.relatedData.targetTableName;
  const saKey    = toSiteAt.relatedData.targetIdAttribute;
  const forKeySA = toSiteAt.relatedData.foreignKey;

  const toSite     = toSiteAt.site();
  const siteTable  = toSite.relatedData.targetTableName;
  const siteKey    = toSite.relatedData.targetIdAttribute;
  const forKeyS    = toSite.relatedData.foreignKey;

  const toContact   = toSite.siteSupervisor();
  const contctTable = toContact.relatedData.targetTableName;
  const contctKey   = toContact.relatedData.targetIdAttribute;
  const forKeyC     = toContact.relatedData.foreignKey;

  return Incident.query( qb => {
    qb.innerJoin(saTable,     `${incTable}.${forKeySA}`, `${saTable}.${saKey}`)
      .innerJoin(siteTable,   `${saTable}.${forKeyS}`,   `${siteTable}.${siteKey}`)
      .innerJoin(contctTable, `${siteTable}.${forKeyC}`, `${contctTable}.${contctKey}`)
      .whereIn(`${contctTable}.id`, myContactId);    // <1>
  }).fetchAll();
```

<1> Here's your *Contact ID*

Question to everyone else: Is there actually some more "Bookshelf-y" way to solve this?

Comment: I greatly appreciate another take at this, especially since this is only one query to fetch the required information.  Perhaps since no one has viewed this answer though, it is worth creating a new question with your solution and asking for the best "Bookshelf-y" way?